# JavaScript library for candlestick charts stacked ontop of volume bars, with pictures on top of the data points

Tags: javascript, html, charts, jquery

I need a javascript charting library that will fit my needs as I will elaborate. I need to be able to create multi series candlestick charts stacked ontop of volume bars, and I also need to be draw pictures on top of the data points. And I need to be able to have a range slider at the bottom to look at old datapoints.

I was using google.visualization, but as soon as I put a range filter on it, it broke my needs, as trying to get the positions on the chart converted into coordinates, so that I could draw images on top of the candles on a canvas I positioned ontop of it, got broken (seems I have to stretch them out from the middle). But I was just annoyed and I started looking at canvasJS, because they use a canvas, so I didn't have to create my own canvas on top and I read that drawing on a canvas is better on memory because it's not creating new dom elements everytime there is data added to it, and this is dynamic data. Plus the range filter available in google visulization sucks because it doesn't really look good when you have multi series, as it looks ugly and I originally just wanted a slider that I could slide back and forth to look at older data as it is a live chart connected to a websocket I am making. And I can't do that in google.visulizations.

So I started trying to use canvasJS, but I couldn't find a way to have both a multi series candlestick data and volume bars underneath complete with there own separate y axis labels. So I created two charts and put them underneath each other. But then I had to line up the y axis, and I figured out how to do that, but the problem is they force you to render it before doing the calculations you need to do to line it up, so I had to render it, adjust the axis, and re-render it, over and over again as this is dynamic data. I tried getting around this by rendering first to an invisible div then copying to a visible canvas, but the y axis was no longer visible for some reason. I tried resetting the size of the visible canvas based on the bounds of the invisible chart, but still there was no y axis for some reason. Maybe I could figure it out, but the fact that I have to do hackish things to make the library fit my needs just because they don't have the exact features I need is not ideal, and I could waste a lot of time trying to get it to work, as I already have.

I could keep looking at more libraries, but what if I discover more ways they don't fit my needs. But maybe there are some suggestions that could be given. I am getting to the point where I am thinking about creating my own chart from scratch in HTML5 canvas without a library.

Comment: https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/interactive-candlestick-chart?framework=javascript

Comment: @Syed There is a free trial for FusionCharts however the basic plan is at 499$/year.

Comment: Actually, I just ended up drawing my own chart from scratch in javascript. I haven't seen anything in any charting library that things exactly the way I wanted to do them, including in ECharts. That slider design is not at all the way I wanted to design things, I just wanted left and right triangle shape buttons for sliding left and right and I ended up putting up and down triangle shape buttons for zooming in and out. The only thing I could do was draw my charts from scratch to get my custom solution. It wasn't that hard to do from scratch either. I don't know why people have told me before,

Comment: @user904542: I encourage you to post your code on GitHub, so that others can reuse it. If you do, please feel free to post an answer about it below :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SciChart's [JavaScript Chart](http://scichart.com/javascript-chart-features/) fits a lot of these needs, here's a quick rundown

1. Supports candlestick, line, mountain, area, column, scatter charts (and more)
2. Has a scrollbar overview slider to look back at old data
3. Supports realtime updates, e.g. if you pipe data from exchange into the chart
4. Is super high performance being able to draw millions of datapoints
5. Looks awesome and easily themeable

[image: React JavaScript Candlestick Chart]

Here's a live demo: [Realtime Javascript Candlestick Chart demo](https://demo.scichart.com/javascript-realtime-ticking-stock-charts)

What this does:

- It's fetching price data from Binance (BTC/USDT) via REST API
- Piping this into a candlestick chart
- Calculating two moving averages based on the data using the filters/functions API and updating those as well
- Drawing volume bars at the footer of the chart
- Subscribing to price updates via web socket
- Allows zooming, panning, an active legend as well as a scrollbar control to go back in time

Click the [demo above](https://demo.scichart.com/javascript-realtime-ticking-stock-charts) to see links for where the source-code is on Github.

FYI SciChart is commercial software however there is a [free community edition](https://www.scichart.com/community-licensing/) for non-commercial, educational & blogger use

Answer (score 0):

## ECharts

Apache [ECharts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) is an Open Source JavaScript Visualization Library. You can try it online. Just click on an example and modify the source code.

[Examples for candlestick charts](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/#chart-type-candlestick)

[Example with a slider and volume bar](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=candlestick-large)

- For the slider there are arrows (left and right) to select a duration (range). And on mouse over there are plus signs at left and right to change period (date).